# Serilog Exception System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I have a constant variable that I use to only print a message in my log and it shows me this error

```
string const AppMessages.Infos.StartEnqueueProcess = "Starting proccess";
_logger.LogInformation(AppMessages.Infos.StartEnqueueProcess);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frYRO.png)

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Print log without error.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code posted.  The code posted is showing code for logging errors, not the actual error.  The error is in the service Enhesa.  The reference code is "OLAFFVE-01"

Comment: please add the text to your question instead of linking an image